# Magento Custom Admin Page with URL outside of the adminpath

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, module

I am trying to build a custom Magento module which creates an admin page in Magento. I have everything working fineexcept the admin page url is domain.com/index.php/module/controllername/function/
when it should be 
domain.com/index.php/adminpath/module/controllername/function/

```
    <Module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Developer_Module_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>Module</frontName>
            </args>
        </Module>

    </routers>
    <!--<routers>
       <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <module>
                    <Developer_Module after="Mage_Adminhtml">Developer_Module_Adminhtml</Developer_Module>
                </module>
            </args>
       </adminhtml>
    </routers>-->
```

And my admin menu link is

```
<menu1 translate="title" module="Module">
            <title>Developer</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="Module">
                    <title>Page Link</title>
                    <action>module/function</action> //setting this adminhtml/module/function just gives 404 but changes url to what i want
                </menuitem1>
            </children>                
        </menu1>
```

So i'm wondering how i set my module to be within the standard admin path properly?

Comment: First thing - you should be using the commented out way to create admin routes, not the top way - since SUPEE 6788 it's a security risk

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! The other way doesn't work? I will install some updates and see if it changes it since that update.

Comment: It may still work, but it's the "old style" of writing admin routes

Comment: Well the reason i want to change it is a security risk i doubt same one as you have mentioned but just anyone installing a module like this it gives a second url to login to admin and more chance of finding admin panel, as well as allowing access to outside IP's if this url hasn't been blocked so i want to change it.